# Back-propagation in word2vec

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, word2vec

In supervised learning the error is computed using the labels of training set. However, in unsupervised we do not have labels. How the error is computed in this case.

More specifically, in word2vec how the error is computed after forwardprop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

word2vec is a *supervised* learning algorithm.

Suppose your text corpus is made of the sentence "I like playing football". Say that we use CBOW with an asymmetric window of length=1, where the context word is represented by the word that precedes the center word. The center word is our target (or label). For the example above, our training examples would be like in the figure below

[image]

- The first training example would be:
  **input**: "I"; **label**: "like"
- The second one would be:
  **input**: "like"; **label**: "playing"
- The third one would be:
  **input**: "playing"; **label**: "football"

After one-hot encoding the words in our corpus (according to their order of appearance), we get these training examples:

1) **input**: [1, 0, 0, 0]; **label**: [0, 1, 0, 0]

2) **input**: [0, 1, 0, 0]; **label**: [0, 0, 1, 0]

3) **input**: [0, 0, 1, 0]; **label**: [0, 0, 0, 1]

Now, training the CBOW network means finding (through backpropagation and gradient descent) those values of the weights for which the prediction is as close as possible to the label, given the corresponding input (context word/words).

In the Skip-gram model, the input becomes the center word and the label the context words.

I hope this helps, but you can find a lot more information in [this blogpost](http://www.claudiobellei.com/2018/01/06/backprop-word2vec/).

Comment: Glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 2):

Word2vec has two versions:

In the **skip-gram** version, the label is the contexts of the input word. By the context I mean the surrounding words.

In the **CBOW** version (continuous bag of words), the input is the context of a word and the label is the word itself.

In fact, word2vec tries to learn the vector representation for each word that best describes its context.

Comment: I only need to know how backpropagation is happening for instance in CBOW version

Comment: I think the answer is clear. When you have the labels you can use backprop as in any supervised learning scenario. As mentioned, the labels are defined according to the context of the words as mentioned.

Comment: can u clarify how the error is computed in order to get weight matrixes